# Why does my fork block if I yield it immediately?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, generator, redux-saga

I have a saga which is suppose to query a third party tool to collect state for the UI.  Due to the extensive number of calls, and how I have to build the tree of calls, I'm trying to have a method that starts the requests with fork, allowing me to make a dozen in parallel as I piece together the calls I need, and a second method to join the forked calls and collect the results.

My query method, that should start the calls, looks like this:

```
* asyncQuery(action, domain, config) {
   let baseUrl;

   if (config && domain) {
      baseUrl = getBaseUrl(config.deployments, domain);
   }  else {
      baseUrl = yield select(selectUrlForDomain(domain));
   }

   return yield fork(this.doManualGetRequest, action.payload.apiPath, baseUrl);
}


 doManualGetRequest(apiPath, baseUrl) {

     const url = buildUrl(basUrl, apiPath);

     const requestPromise = fetch(url, options)
         .then(checkStatus)
         .then(parseJSON)
         .then((data) => ({ data }))
         .catch((err) => ({ err }));
}
```

This is called by some logic which is responsible for building up a tree of requests, and which adds each call to a queue.  Before calling joinRequets:

```
* joinRequests(requestsMap) {
    const results = {}
    const requests = Object.entries(requestsMap)


    join(Object.values(requestsMap));

    for (let i = 0; i < requests.length; i++) {

       const [key, request] = request[i];

       results[key] = request.result();
    }

    return results;
}
```

After some expeirmentation I discovered that each call to doManualGetRequest is blocking.  Specifically I can watch in my networking tab as one call is made only after the last call completes, and I've used print statements and a sleep to confirm for sure that a new fork is not called until the promise returned by doManualGetRequest finishes executing.

If I instead do not yield the fork command in asyncQuery, and instead do a yield in joinRequest prior to running the join command, I see all of the queries being sent out at once in a proper async manner.

Why does yielding in doManualGetRequest lead to a blocking behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yield`ing a `fork` in `doManualGetRequest` blocks because `doManualGetRequest` **waits for the forked process before returning.**  The docs are a bit tricky here, if you look closely you can find out why.

From the docs:

> All forked tasks are attached to their parents. When the parent terminates the execution of its own body of instructions, **it will wait for all forked tasks to terminate before returning.**

https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#forkfn-args

So if you had more code in `doManualGetRequest` after `yield fork`, that code would run immediately after you forked the process.  However, `doManualGetRequest` will not **return** until the `fork` is complete (or failed).

The purpose of `fork` is so you can attach a reference to the async task and potentially cancel it or check if its still running.  Your case, you don't need that functionality.  **Please try `spawn` instead.**

From the docs, **spawn(fn, ...args)**:

> Same as fork(fn, ...args) but creates a detached task. A detached task remains independent from its parent and acts like a top-level task. **The parent will not wait for detached tasks to terminate before returning** and all events which may affect the parent or the detached task are completely independents (error, cancellation).

https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#spawnfn-args

Comment: Using spawn appears to have the exact same issue, it still blocks my function from returning, despite what the docs say